# reading email id from a file and replacing it

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010 and I have,

**qiongshuailv@163.com i**

**e_sqwang@zzu.edu.cn**

these are two email id which is given in a xml file what I want to do is that I want to find the ids and replace it with

**< email >qiongshuailv@163.com< /email >**

**< email >ie_sqwang@zzu.edu.cn< /email >**

Now the problem is that the email id may change in different files so is it possible to replace the id with the above statement for every other email id.

Please anyone that can help me with the logic, it will be appreciated.

Comment: If they're given in an XML file, they should already be between some tags. Just pick the values and append your own tags.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault as I suspect, the emails are not between tags. The program is to correct this problem, and replace each line with tags around the emails.

Comment: If you have some code, then please share with us Jigar.

Comment: yes you are right aniket and sorry i dont have any code because i am not familiar with the regular expressions

Comment: so please can you help me with the required logic

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
string path = "Sample.txt";
File.WriteAllLines(path, File.ReadLines(path).Select(x => string.Format("<email>{0}</email>", x)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Should do the trick, unless there's already other stuff in the file, like XML headers and so on, which is fairly possible.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault It's not clear how file looks like, let OP clear it.

Comment: the email id are not in the tag instead i have to find eg. abcd@abcd.com in a xml file and replace the id with <email> tags eg.<email>abcd@abcd.com</email>

Comment: Post how your complete file look like

Comment: <aff id="aff1"><institution>Information Engineering School Zhengzhou University Zhengzhou</institution>, China qiongshuailv@163.com</aff>
<aff id="aff2"><institution>Information Engineering School Zhengzhou University Zhengzhou</institution>, China ie&#x005F;sqwang@zzu.edu.cn</aff>                                                it is something like this as u can see the email_id is not in an <email></email> tag

Comment: i need to find "qiongshuailv@163.com" and "ie&#x005F;sqwang@zzu.edu.cn" among all the lines and replace it with

Comment: <email>qiongshuailv@163.com</email> and <email>ie&#x005F;sqwang@zzu.edu.cn</email> plz note that email id can change in the future so i need an expresion that files the email id automatically in the lines of the given file

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps, regardless of C# or VB.NET:

- . Read the file, line by line into a `List<string> list`
- . Close the file, reopen the file for writing
- . `foreach(var s in list){ file.Write("<email>"+s+"</email>");}`